# ethers js queryFilter for ERC20 list of addresses

Tags: erc-20, ethers.js, logs, typescript

Is there a way to get the list of transferred ERC20 tokens to a list of addresses in one call.

Right now I am running

```
const events = await contract.queryFilter(erc20Contract.filters.Transfer, fromBlockNumber, toBlockNumber);
```

on each

```
provider.on('block', (blockNumber: number) => {...}
```

I am running this for USDC and I am only interested in a small list of destination addresses.

Is there a way to query only for these destination addresses or am I forced to pull all USDC transfers each block ?

I found this: https://docs.ethers.org/v5/concepts/events/#events--filters

but unable to implement the same with TypeScript and ethers js v6

Anyone been able to do this? Is this optimisation even worth it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dev advocate at [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com/) here!

You can use `ethers.js` do do this! Here is an example with `USDC` and three random addresses. This is based on ethers V5.

```js
const { ethers } = require("ethers");

const providerUrl =
  "YOUR_NODE_URL";

// Connect to the Ethereum network
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(providerUrl);

// ERC20 Contract Address (e.g. USDC)
const contractAddress = "0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48";

// ERC20 ABI (Simplified for Transfer event)
const erc20Abi = [
  "event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint amount)",
];

// Create a new contract instance
const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, erc20Abi, provider);

// Define the addresses to monitor for incoming transfers
const addresses = [
  "0x61a94BD03562BeF44093bd38b26F148B61Aa7f01",
  "0x49dC50bcA05de468fb5913a4079c24a9d9183Dc5",
  "0xbb23Ad179186Fa962B51Ea29011a461281e797E5",
];

// Optionally, specify the block range (startBlock and endBlock)
const startBlock = 18977593; // Start block number
const endBlock = 18977617; // Use 'latest' for the most recent block

// Function to fetch and log transfer events for a given address
async function fetchTransferEvents(toAddress) {
  const filter = {
    fromBlock: startBlock,
    toBlock: endBlock,
    address: contractAddress,
    topics: [
      ethers.utils.id("Transfer(address,address,uint256)"),
      null,
      ethers.utils.hexZeroPad(toAddress, 32), // Pad the address to 32 bytes
    ],
  };

  try {
    const logs = await provider.getLogs(filter);
    logs.forEach((log) => {
      const parsedLog = contract.interface.parseLog(log);
      console.log(
        `Transfer to ${toAddress}: From ${
          parsedLog.args.from
        } Amount: ${(parsedLog.args.amount.toString())}`
      );
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`Error fetching logs for address ${toAddress}:`, err);
  }
}

// Fetch transfer events for each address
addresses.forEach(fetchTransferEvents);
```

This will give you the transfers to the specified addresses in the block range you define:

```js
const startBlock = 18977593; // Start block number
const endBlock = 18977617; // Use 'latest' for the most recent block
```

Comment: Thanks but this would result in 3 separate calls to `provider.getLogs` which is what I am currently doing. I was wondering if there is a way to do it in one call

Comment: Yeah, what you are saying makes sense. You could fetch all the logs for the block range and then scan the results to see if the addresses you want are there; it might be less efficient. I'll try that approach and add it to the answer. You could also run every block with eth_getBlockReceipts and try to find the needed events, which is also possibly more resource-intensive.

Comment: I am using alchemy to query the logs and trying to stay within the free tier

Comment: Makes sense. I don't want to shill here as this is not the place for that, but you can try Chainstack too: https://chainstack.com/; I'm a dev advocate for them. Full disclosure. But even on the free tier, you shouldn't have an issue staying within the limits.